# Remove space before a listing in a frame

Tags: floats, listings

I am typesetting a document where I want to include some code samples. With each code sample, I want to have some introduction text and in some cases a note after the example.

To accomplish this I am using a `\begin{figure}` and inside of this I have one or more `\begin{lstlisting}`.

The issue I am having is that before the `lstlisting` there is a lot of whitspace. In the full document, this makes it hard to see this as a concise block of the document separate from the content. After the `lstlisting` the amount of space is okay.

I am hoping there is something I can add to `\lstset{}` in my preamble to fix this.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of my issue]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,listings,graphicx,usenix,epsfig,textcomp,xcolor}

\makeatletter

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language=html,     
    frame=single,
    tabsize=2,
    title=\lstname,
    escapechar=�,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true,
    upquote=true,
    breaklines=true, 
    rulecolor=\color{black!30},
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    identifierstyle=\color{magenta!50!black},
    stringstyle=\color{blue},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    framextopmargin=2pt,
    framexbottommargin=2pt, 
}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}

\textit{\emph{\footnotesize{Code Example for }}}\texttt{\textit{\emph{\footnotesize{example.com:}}}}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},language=HTML]
<div id="div1">foo</div> 
\end{lstlisting}


\textit{\emph{\footnotesize{Another code example}}}{\footnotesize \par}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},language=HTML]
<div id="div2">bar</div> 
\end{lstlisting}

\caption{Cation Title Goes Here \label{fig:caption-example} }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

I am using XeLaTeX if that matters. I am also open to other ways of arranging this if its not going to be big hassle to manage in Lyx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\lstname` is undefined, and probably [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) treats as empty/blank and sets nothing for the listing title. However, this still takes up an entire line at the top of each `lstlisting`. So, remove `title=\lstname` in your `\lstset`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor,textcomp}

\makeatletter

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language=html,     
    frame=single,
    tabsize=2,
    escapechar=�,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true,
    upquote=true,
    breaklines=true, 
    rulecolor=\color{black!30},
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    identifierstyle=\color{magenta!50!black},
    stringstyle=\color{blue},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    framextopmargin=2pt,
    framexbottommargin=2pt, 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\textit{\emph{\footnotesize{Code Example for }}}\texttt{\textit{\emph{\footnotesize{example.com:}}}}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},language=HTML]
<div id="div1">foo</div> 
\end{lstlisting}

\textit{\emph{\footnotesize{Another code example}}}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},language=HTML]
<div id="div2">bar</div> 
\end{lstlisting}

\caption{Cation Title Goes Here \label{fig:caption-example} }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```